# CTE Execution Order

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

In the following CTE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (Field1 INTEGER, Field2 INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE test_table2 (Field1 INTEGER, Field2 INTEGER);

WITH table_stage1(fld1, fld2) AS
    (SELECT Field1, Field2 from test_table1)
, table_stage2 AS 
    (SELECT fld1, fld2 FROM table_stage1 GROUP BY fld1, fld2)
, table_stage3 AS 
    (SELECT fld1 FROM table_stage1 GROUP BY fld1)
INSERT INTO test_table2(Field1, Field2)
    SELECT t1.fld1, t2.fld2
        FROM table_stage2 t1
        JOIN table_stage3 t2
    ON t1.fld1 = t2.fld1;
```

Can I assume the following order of query execution:

1. `SELECT` inside WITH statemt
2. Concurrent execution of `SELECT` inside `table_stage2`, and `table_stage3` segments
3. `INSERT INTO` waits till execution of `table_stage2`, `table_stage3` is finished

This question is not related to a particular (presented) statement.

I would like to know if by selecting from a named segment there is a guarantee the current statement will be executed after the particular named segment.
Meybe what is significat is having a number of select statements folowed by a write CTE that joins results from previous segments

The PostgeSQL [documentations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html) we can read:

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other
>   and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying
>   statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually
>   happen is unpredictable.

I am working on PostgreSQL 9.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The part of the documentation that you cite refers to the execution of more than one data-modifying statement (using data-modifying statements ... the order is unpredictable). But if in one of the statement is used the *name* of a previous statement, this means that the current statement refer to *all the tuples* returned by the previous one.

So, in your example the statements relative to `table_stage2` and `table_stage3` can be executed in parallel, but using all the tuples returned by table_stage1, while the final `insert` will be executed by using all the tuples returned by the previous two statements (and so by using all the tuples produced by the previous three statements).

Note that: “B uses all the tuples returned by A” is not necessarily equivalent to: “B is executed after A”: the optimizer can in fact transform B so that it is not necessary to execute A. It is just a semantics definition, and is not related to an actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Recently, I was prepering a CTE query and noticed that I got two different results depending on if I put a select statement as a separate statement (A) and then insert based in this result or if I used the same statement but directly as a nested sub select in the final insert. It looked like in the fist case the final insert was executed before the A was completed. I did not analyze the execution plan, but your final note may explain this.

Comment: Is there any way to force a certain execution order? E.g. A inserts data into table X, B selects from table X. Right now B is run before A despite that the code is written WITH (A) B.

Comment: @fgblomqvist, no, it is not possibile since you can have several selects, or one update/insert/delete which follows a set of selects, so you cannot perform first an update/insert/delete and then a select.